# Convert custom string date to date

Tags: python, date

Is there a way to convert a string date that is stored in some non-traditional custom manner into a date using `datetime` (or something equivalent)? The dates I am dealing with are S3 partitions that look like this:

`year=2023/month=2/dayofmonth=3`

I can accomplish this with several `replace`s but im hoping to find a clean single operation to do this.

Comment: I think regex would be helpful here. You would be able to construct a one-liner, though readability will suffer.

Comment: Put your current implementation into a function, so calling it will be a "singe operation".

Comment: Did you tried with datetime.strptime(stringofdate, "year=%Y/month=%m/dayofmonth=%d")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might provide `datetime.datetime.strptime` with format string holding text, in this case

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("year=2023/month=2/dayofmonth=3","year=%Y/month=%m/dayofmonth=%d")
d = dt.date()
print(d) # 2023-02-03
```

Comment: TIL i never really knew how to use `strptime`

Answer (score 2):

you can do that converting your string into a date object using "datetime" combined with strptime() method.

The strtime() takes two arguments, the first is the string to be parsed, and the second a string with the format.

Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

# your string
date_string = "year=2023/month=2/dayofmonth=3"

# parse the string into a datetime object
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, "year=%Y/month=%m/dayofmonth=%d")

# print the datetime object
print(date)
```